# C# Save PictureBox Image to Remote Server

Tags: c#, image, picturebox, remote-server

I have my own server with local IP is 172.23.1.66 with CentOS 7

So in my program, I can call image from my server with string imageLocation = "http://172.23.1.66/img/978979892782.jpg";

In other case, I want to save it in to my remote server. I can't access it in windows explorer, I only can access it on browser. I remote it using WinSCP.

I have try like this:

```
picImage.Image.Save(@"\\172.23.1.66\img\" + clsLibrary.throwCode + ".jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg); // throwCode is my file name
```

but it throw **An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll**

I also have try delete **\\** in the first of IP.

Everything is fail, can anyone help?

Comment: Write the image into a temporary file, then send it using [SFTP](http://blog.deltacode.be/2012/01/05/uploading-a-file-using-sftp-in-c-sharp/)

Comment: you can write a small c++ or python server where you can send an image file buffer from c# program and after receiving it server program will save it in you given path

Answer (score 0):

Use Server MapPath to make sure you can use your URL on your server:

```
picImage.Image.Save(Server.MapPath("~/img/") + clsLibrary.throwCode + ".jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: It show me an error **The name 'Server' does not exist in the current context**

Comment: Try this instead: System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath.

Comment: Well now I have this error **The type or namespace name 'HttpContext' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)**.. I don't know what happen, I already try **using System.Web;** and use your code but I still get the same error. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and now my code like this **picImage.Image.Save(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("172.23.1.66/img/") + clsLibrary.throwCode + ".jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);** What is happening?

Comment: I have add new references and it's not error anymore, but when I run that code, I got a new error **An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Pusat Penerbit dan Bookshop USD.exe**

Answer (score 0):

-you are only allowed to get Image using IP address.To save Image on IP address-

```
 public string TEMP_PATH = "~/Temp/ImagesPath/";
```

Make sure that you have proper right to access /Temp/ImagesPath/.

After That

```
try
        {
            FileInfo fileDatails = new FileInfo(AsyncImageUpload.PostedFile.FileName);/* here you can get file using you source like OFD or FileUpload Controls */
            string exten = fileDatails.Extension;
            Stream fs = this.AsyncImageUpload.FileContent;
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
            Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length); /* convert file to byte */
            String Base64file = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
            destinationPath = Server.MapPath(TEMP_PATH + fileDatails.Name);
            Byte[] frombytes = Convert.FromBase64String(Base64file);
            File.WriteAllBytes(destinationPath, frombytes); /*write file to destination folder on server */
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            throw exp;
        }
```

Comment: Do I need http:// or just my IP? I have an access to ~/img/ using WinSCP

Comment: What is file variable declaration? Is that stream file?

Comment: hi Bowi...Please see updated code. No need to mention http:// or IP. Instead Declare  public string TEMP_PATH = "~/img/"; if your application also running on same remote server.